# Live broadcast use of WebRtc in android is it possible.?

Tags: android, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I want to develop Live Streaming like **Facebook** using `WebRtc`. is it possible..? I already develop this thing using `WOWZA`. want to develop the same this with `WebRtc`.

Comment: What is the goal of streaming with WebRTC in your case?Wowza already offer [webrtc streaming](https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software). Facebook doesn't stream with WebRTC they stream with MPEG-DASH which is closer to the HLS you probably currently serve.

The only reason to use WebRTC media channels (and not HLS or DASH) is very low latency since it is more expensive and a lot less cache friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With the bandwidth cost catching up on the CDN costs, the price difference, if any, between file-based solutions over HTTP(s) (HLS, MPEG-DASH, ..) and direct streaming solutions (RTMP, WebRTC, RTSP, direct transport: STR, WS, QUIC, ...) are vanishing.
- Direct streaming solutions have better latency by design, even when "optimised", including with webrtc p2p offload (peer5, streaming root).
- The two main drawbacks of WebRTC were scalability and Apple devices:

One needed a file-based system to reach out to Apple device since they banned flash. It's not the case anymore and you can reach a web app in safari with webrtc using H.264. It will be extended to all apps using the web view framework later this year.

WebRTC open source servers are not cascadable, and one server is limited to around 1,000 viewers. But both Vidyo and Xirsys have commercial solutions for that.

If you wanted to have a solution for "real-time" live streaming (latency < 500ms) as opposed to Facebook live streaming (few seconds latency), you could reach out to the two aforementioned companies. There is AFAIK, nothing open source today to solve that problem.